# ViewCompat's inset listener returns wrong values for older APIs

Tags: android, kotlin, windowinsets

I want to get the height and visibility of the status bar so I use `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener`, this works as expected for my API 30 and 33 devices. However using older devices (API 25 and 23) I always get the same inset values regardless of the visibility of the status bar.

I set the listener like this in the Activity's `onCreate()`

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(window.decorView) { view, insets ->
            val systembarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            val statusbarInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())

            Timber.d("Listener status insets: $statusbarInsets, bar visible: ${insets.isVisible(
                WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())}")

            Timber.d("Listener system insets: $systembarInsets, bar visible: ${insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())}")

            insets
//            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
//            ViewCompat.onApplyWindowInsets(view, insets)
        }
```

For the older APIs, the initial inset values never change (it may be all 0 or the status/nav bar heights) even when I toggle immersive mode on and off.

As you can see in the code I tried to change the return value but none of the 3 options fixed the issue.

The deprecated method `setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` works correctly but I thought `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` was supposed to mimic its behavior in older API versions.